# change in field of Eager Loading in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 table, "nostalgia" and "user" that there is relation between them, in user model i wrote:

```
public function nostalgia(){
    return $this->hasMany(Nostalgia::class);
}

public function getPrivatePhone(){
    return substr_replace($this->phone,"***",4,3);
}
```

and in the nostalgia model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

now i want to get all nostalgia in pagination mode, with relation to the user table to get user phone, that i want to change some of character of phone number by "getPrivatePhone()" that i define in user model, or in anyway.
how can i do this?
i try this query with eager loading but cant change phone number:

```
Nostalgia::Where("confirm", "=", true)->with('user:id,phone')->Latest()->paginate(6),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your `User` model as below:

```
class User extends Model{

  protected $appends = ['privatePhone'];

  protected $visible = ['id', 'phone', 'privatePhone']

  public function getPrivatePhoneAttribute()
  {
    return substr_replace($this->phone,"***",4,3);
  }

  //Remove the method getPrivatePhone()
  //And keep everything else as it is
}
```

`$nostalgias = Nostalgia::Where("confirm", true)->with('user')->Latest()->paginate(6);`

Now, you can access a like:

`$nostalgias->first()->user->privatePhone`

or in Loop:

```
foreach($nostalgias as $nostalgia){
  $nostalgia->user->privatePhone;
}
```

Comment: its awesome but i want to use this query as api, and i dont want to get all user data in query, how can i select just "privatePhone"

Comment: Updated the question, see the `User` model with visible property.